# redirect only once and save visitor ip

Tags: php, arrays

the code works fine but when it has 200 ip stored it deletes it automatically and I want it to not delete any ip unless I delete them manually

```
$ipfile = "ips.txt";
$ips = explode("\n",file_get_contents($ipfile));
$isban = 0;
foreach($ips as $ip) {
    $ip = explode(" ",$ip,2);
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $ip['0']) {
        $isban++; 
    }
}
if(!empty($isban))
{
    die("IP IS BANNED!");
}
else
{
    $ips[] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." ".date("d/m/y");
    $ips = implode("\n",$ips);
    file_put_contents($ipfile,$ips);
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
    exit;
}
```

I want it to store all the ip without deleting it, it does not matter if I have to use a database so that it can work better or some solution that someone brings to me.

Comment: Have you checked your PHP Error logs?

Comment: The way you are storing the whole file content in one string variable, you "might" be hitting a limit of some kind. If you must use a text file solution then try file() that reads the file to an array. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php otherwise it is better to use database.

Comment: There is nothing in your code mentioning 200 or deleting files. Please post the code that shows it happening

Comment: I'm not having any errors in the logs @RiggsFolly

Comment: If I delete them automatically when it reaches a limit of 200 to 300 ips, I send a lot of traffic at the same time, can that be why? @MatthewPage

Comment: can you help me use this PHP with a database? @NawedKhan

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, although I'm not sure what the foreach does. It seems it can be replaced with a `count()` or in_array or something. But I believe the problem lies in PHPs text file handling. If two people use a code at the same time that uses the same text file only one of them will succeed. The other will see the file as missing and will create it (replace the file with an empty file). Of course the larger the file is the higher the risk is that this will happen since it will take longer to open and read the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is much easier using database. Here is example.

In Mysql:

```
CREATE DATABASE addr;
USE addr;

CREATE TABLE ips (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ip VARCHAR(45),
  visit_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now()
);
```

In PHP:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','addr');

$remote_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip = '$remote_ip'";

$isban = mysqli_num_rows($conn ->query($query2));


if($isban > 0){
    die("IP IS BANNED!");
}
else{

    $query = "INSERT INTO ips (ip) VALUE ('$remote_ip')";

    $conn->query($query);

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: this has worked for me a lot of thanks that god bless you I have stored 90,000 ips and it works correctly

Answer (score 1):

This code has no error handling, therefore it is impossible to learn *early* about what fails so that you can't address it specifically.

What does that mean? Let's see exemplary this line of code (I've taken it from the code of your question, but I could have taken it from numerous other examples, as such kind of a mistake is quite common in PHP code examples on Stackoverflow):

```
$ips = explode("\n",file_get_contents($ipfile));
```

If `file_get_contents()` fails to load the file it normally is only noticed if you expect the list of `$ips` has entries and then unexpectedly it does not.

That is because the return value of `file_get_contents()` is not checked whether or not an error appeared.

In PHP it is quite common that a function not only returns the result of the function but as well - in case of an error - the error result of it.

For every function which differs that way in the return value, it needs to be treated for the different ways.

This is especially crucial w/ i/o operations like reading from a file and writing to a file. you actually want to learn when these operations fail and then proceed accordingly.

To repeat the example: If reading the file fails, this is not an empty string to progress with resulting in data-loss of all recordsets (in your case your file actually is a database and one record is one line in it). But if not treated differently, it will become so, which is in your example the
deletion of all IPs.

## How To Solve?

Review the use of I/O related functions in the code. This can be easily achieved by going through each function call and check the manual entries regarding their error handling and especially the return values.

Then improve your code by handling these error conditions accordingly.

### Further Outlook

Next to error handling there is also something called locks or locking regarding file operations, you could take a read into that to better control congruent execution of the same script as the file is a shared resource here.

Comment: Yesterday I did a test and I have approximately 460 ips stored but I think that when many users enter at the same time the script does not support and deletes all the ips that are in the text file also I just saw that after I entered the link and I block my ip and then enter 100 or 150 users but my ip is already unlocked will be that the script can not read as many ips at the same time?

Comment: Yeah no wonder. Add the error handling first, should at least spare you loosing 480 IPs. Next thing you'll run into will be race conditions and [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use), the operating system / filesystem should provide you anything to at least not loose the data, depending on how fast your script is, you won't even see deadlocks at all.